# Use a different class for each build variant

Tags: android, android-studio, build-variant

I have an Application class that I want to be different in each build variant like debug and release.
this is my map:

```
app/      
   |      
   |----debug/          
             |----java\            
                       |----com.example.App.class       
             |----res\
                      |----mipmap-hdpi       
   |----main/          
             |----java\      
                      |----com.example.App.class       
             |----res\
                      |----mipmap-hdpi
```

but in android studio give me this error message **"duplicate class found in ..."**
but it does not show any error in my resources.
my question is why gradle cannot figure it out what class should use in different build variant but it can decide what resource must be used in different build variants.

Comment: Instead of using same class twice, why not configure the `BuildConfig` class in `build.gradle` ?

Comment: a little more explanation, please.

Comment: I guess you're referring to the `App.class` twice under `buildTypes` for achieving different functionalities?

Comment: yes its what I want to do

Comment: place an `if(BuildConfig.debug)` and else condition for every code that depends on build types in your `main` else follow the correct approach that has been answered by @laalto below.

Comment: yes but the problem is that I have dependency with debugImplementation and I don't have that dependency on the release so I have to make it comment and uncomment every time I want to change build variant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Code under `main` is shared between all build types. Hence the class is there twice, once from `debug` and again from `main`.

To have build type specific source files, put them under build type specific folders instead of `main`. For example if you have the usual `debug` and `release` build types, put the other variant under `release`.

Why this is not needed for resources is because [resource merging](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html#resource_merging) can override resources over build types. There is no code merging.